# First, last and sometime middle name detection Java

Tags: java, split, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a code to give off the user's name in different formats after they enter it. However, if a user does not have a middle name, the system should print that there was an error. I have it so it works perfectly if the user enters three names but does not work if the user enters two names. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    String fullName;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print ("What are your first, middle, and last names? ");
    fullName = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(fullName);
    if (fullName.contains(" "))
    {
      String[] nameParts = fullName.split(" ");
      String firstInitial = nameParts[0].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
      String secondInitial = nameParts[1].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
      String thirdInitial = nameParts[2].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();

      if (nameParts[2].isEmpty())
      {
        System.out.println("No Middle Name Detected");
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println ("Your initials are: " + firstInitial + secondInitial + thirdInitial);

        String lastVariationOne = nameParts[2].substring(0, nameParts[2].length());
        lastVariationOne = lastVariationOne.toUpperCase();
        String firstVariationOne = nameParts[0].substring(0, nameParts[0].length());
        firstVariationOne = firstVariationOne.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + firstVariationOne.substring(1, nameParts[0].length());
        System.out.println("Variation One: " + lastVariationOne + ", " + firstVariationOne + " " + secondInitial + ".");

        String lastVariationTwo = nameParts[2].substring(0, nameParts[2].length());
        lastVariationTwo = lastVariationTwo.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + lastVariationTwo.substring(1, nameParts[2].length());
        System.out.println("Variation Two: " + lastVariationTwo + ", " + firstVariationOne);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("Wrong. Please enter your name properly.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If the user only enters two names, then the length of the `nameParts` array will only be 2, not 3...

Comment: My father doesn't have a middle name, does that make him an error?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? If the user does not supply a middle name, nameParts[2] will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
if (nameParts[2].isEmpty())
{
    System.out.println("No Middle Name Detected");
}
```

something like

```
if(nameParts.length != 3)
{
    System.out.println("Invalid entry");
}
```

might be preferrable.

Basically, in the case that there are only two names entered, `split()` will return an array of length 2, whose elements are accessible by indices 0 and 1.

But in your `if` condition you attempt to access index 2, which could be out of bounds (it *would* be OOB for the case where you entered only two names).

To resolve this, you could either (a) try it like you do, but catch the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or (b) check first that split produced a properly sized array, then go from there (this was the approach I took with the change I listed).

I'd suggest (b), but both approaches seem fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't input middlename, would the array size be 2? 
So there is NO namespart[2]. 
Just check size of namespart. 
@jedwards jedwards's solution is there.