# If else statements with size of split

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a basic program that outputs the initials and variations of the name the user inputs. I have the basic coding down but am stuck on how to write the if-else statement that will allow the user to input just first and last name without the middle too. Here's the start of the code:

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("What are your first, middle, and last names? ");
String name = scan.nextLine();
String[] partOfName = name.split(" ");

**if ()**
{
  char firstInitial = Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[0].charAt(0));
  char middleInitial= Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[1].charAt(0));
  char lastInitial = Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[2].charAt(0));

  String firstName = partOfName[0].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + partOfName[0].substring(1);

  String lastName = partOfName[2].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + partOfName[2].substring(1);

  String middleName = partOfName[1].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + partOfName[1].substring(1);
  String c_lastName = lastName.toUpperCase();

  System.out.println ("Your Initials Are " + firstInitial + middleInitial + lastInitial);
  System.out.println("Variation one: " + c_lastName + ", " + firstName + " " + middleInitial + ".");
  System.out.println("Variation two: " + lastName+ ", " + firstName + " " + middleName);
}
else
{
  char firstInitial = Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[0].charAt(0));
  char lastInitial = Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[2].charAt(0));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

count number of words entered,

```
if (partOfName.length == 2){
// only First name and last name
}else if (partOfName.length == 3){
// with middle name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("What are your first, middle, and last names? ");
String name = scan.nextLine();
String[] partOfName = name.split(" ");
int len = partOfName.length;


if( len > 2 )
{
   //If user inputs 4 or more words only first three will be evaluated.

  char firstInitial = Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[0].charAt(0));
  char middleInitial= Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[1].charAt(0));
  char lastInitial = Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[2].charAt(0));

  String firstName = partOfName[0].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + partOfName[0].substring(1);

  String lastName = partOfName[2].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + partOfName[2].substring(1);

  String middleName = partOfName[1].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + partOfName[1].substring(1);
  String c_lastName = lastName.toUpperCase();

  System.out.println ("Your Initials Are " + firstInitial + middleInitial + lastInitial);
  System.out.println("Variation one: " + c_lastName + ", " + firstName + " " + middleInitial + ".");
  System.out.println("Variation two: " + lastName+ ", " + firstName + " " + middleName);
}
else if(len == 2)
{
  char firstInitial = Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[0].charAt(0));
  char lastInitial = Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[1].charAt(0));
}
else if ( len < 2)
{
   System.out.println("Bad input");
}
```

OR you can try something similar

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("What are your first, middle, and last names? ");
String name = scan.nextLine();
String[] partOfName = name.split(" ");
int len = partOfName.length;
int i=0;
string initials = "";

if(len >= 2) 
{

    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
       initials += Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[i].charAt(0));
    }

    System.out.println ("Your Initials Are " + initials );

}
```

Another way is to use StringTokenizer class.don't forget to import StringTokenizer

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer; 


Scanner scan=new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("What are your first, middle, and last names? ");
String name = scan.nextLine();

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(name);

String initials = "Your Initials Are: ";


while (st.hasMoreElements()) 
{
    initials += Character.toUpperCase(st.nextElement().charAt(0)));
}

System.out.println( initials );
```

Comment: You might not want to have, `partOfName.length > 2` because a user can input 4 names. I don't think he would want to parse that.

Comment: @RoK No problem. Logic deals with only first three words. 4th one is ignored.

Comment: You want to make the conditions as tight as possible though. The code can look misleading.

Comment: I'm getting an error: cannot find symbol. Should it be name.length instead?

Comment: @user2799775 yes, there was a typo which Mike Christensen corrected

Comment: Agree with @ÖzkanÖZLÜ - The OP should be thinking about these bounds conditions, not us.  Our job here is to steer the poster in the right direction.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, true. The OP should deal with that himself. The bounds of the conditions wasn't really the question he was asking.

Comment: Still getting the error: "cannot find symbol" with a carat under the period in partOfName.length

Comment: updated. can you try again. So we will have a chance to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Got the partOfName.length to work now I get this error when I run it: Exception in thread Array Index out of Bounds Exception 2

Comment: @user2799775 Exception is throwed because you haven't changed else statement in your code. You should have written 0 and 1; not 2.

Comment: @user2799775 change 2 to 1 in else if (len == 2) block. Because a 2 element array can count up to 1. Arrays start counting from 0.

Comment: Now after entering a name the next line comes up as: press any key to continue

Answer (score 0):

```
if (partOfName.length == 3) {

} else if (partOfName.length == 2) {

} else {
   //deal with exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the size of the array `partOfName`.

```
if (partOfName.length>=3)
{
 //work with first name, middle name and last name
} else {
 //work with first name and last name
}
```

Comment: array.length is final field, not a method

Answer (score 0):

I would probably check the `length` property of the array.

```
if (partOfName.length > 2) // At least 3 names entered
{

}
else if (partOfName.length == 2) // Two names entered
{

}
```

You also might want to check if only one name was entered.  Perhaps the user is Madonna.

Comment: I'm getting an error: cannot find symbol. Should it be name.length instead?

Comment: You want to make sure the array `partOfName` has a length of 3 or more, to make sure the input (`name`) was split into 3 or more parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (partOfName.length == 3)
```

You may want to enhance your else statement to make sure split actually got at least 2 parts

Answer (score 0):

First, before setting,

```
    char firstInitial = Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[0].charAt(0));
    char middleInitial= Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[1].charAt(0));
    char lastInitial = Character.toUpperCase(partOfName[2].charAt(0));
```

Make sure that the the array you have after split has three elements. Otherwise your program will fail.
Then you can assume that if the array has two elements, user has entered his name and surname, then you can set the firstInitial and the lastInitial.
if the array's length is three, then you can set firstInitial, middleInitial and lastInitial

```
    int len=partOfName.length;

    // If you need to get more than 3, you should need a more generic solution.
    if (len<2 || len>3 )
    System.out.println("Bad input."); // or throw an Exception

    if (len==3){
    //set initials of name, middle and lastname
    }
    else if (len==2) {
    //set initials of name, and lastname
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I think I understand what you're saying but not 100%

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883130/first-last-and-sometime-middle-name-detection-java?rq=1